# R: calculate value based on the previous row

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate how many trees I have left every year, if I have a source tree population in year n, and I have how many trees have been removed every year. I can't figure out how to properly update my 'remained trees value'?

My aproach:

```
trees = 10
year = c(1,2,3,4,5)
removed = c(2,1,0,1,3)


dd <- data.frame(source_trees = trees, 
                 year = year,
                 removed = removed,
                 remained_trees = trees-removed)
```

Output:

```
> dd
  source_trees year removed remained_trees
1           10    1       2              8    # correct
2           10    2       1              9    # 8-1 -> should be 7
3           10    3       0             10    # 7-0 -> 7
4           10    4       1              9    # 7-1 -> 6
5           10    5       3              7    # 6-3 -> 3
```

I am looking for solution using dplyr, instead of the iterative for loop.

Comment: Read about lead/lag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cumsum`

```
> transform(dd, remained_trees = source_trees - cumsum(removed))
  source_trees year removed remained_trees
1           10    1       2              8
2           10    2       1              7
3           10    3       0              7
4           10    4       1              6
5           10    5       3              3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try using `accumulate` from `purrr` in `tidyverse`, this is another option.

The `accumulate` function will take as arguments: the `removed` column, a function to subtract the `removed` value (.y) from the result of previous row (.x), and the initial value, which in this case would be the first value of `source_trees`.

The [-1] indexing ignores the first result, which otherwise would be the initial value of `source_trees` of 10.

```
library(tidyverse)

dd |>
  mutate(remained_trees = accumulate(
    removed,
    ~ .x - .y,
    .init = first(source_trees)
  )[-1])
```

**Output**

```
  source_trees year removed remained_trees
1           10    1       2              8
2           10    2       1              7
3           10    3       0              7
4           10    4       1              6
5           10    5       3              3
```